# Unsure how to connect the anode in this circuit

Tags: arduino-uno, wires, rgb-led

I am making a game of X and O’s and ran out of pins on the Arduino. After searching on the internet I found out about connecting it in a grid connecting all the anodes in columns and the different colours in rows but I don't know how to connect the anodes so it only turns on only one of the LEDs rather than the other 2 in the grid if they are all connected to ground. The wires I am unsure to connect are the orange ones in the diagram below (bottom left corner). Note the Red on the RGBs are not used so don't need to be connected

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have made the classic rookie mistake with your circuit regarding your LED current limiting resistors.  You have one per LED group instead of one per LED within a group.  The arrangement you have at the moment means that *at best* some LEDs will be dim or not light at all, and *at worst* will result in LEDs burning out.

There should be a resistor in every red, green and blue wire in your diagram.

As for what to do with the three orange wires (once you have re-arranged the resistors) they connect to three spare IO pins on the Arduino - you then turn each column on or off as you need - only one column is on at a time.  If you need more than 20mA for a column (which is highly likely with up to 9 LEDs on at a time) then those lines should be connected to either +5V or GND (depending on if you are common anode or common cathode) via transistors and the transistors should be switched by the IO pins.

Comment: So you just connect it to the 3 analogue pins and how would you code it if it would normally go to the ground

Comment: If they are common cathode (normally connect to ground) then set a pin HIGH to turn a column off, or LOW to turn it on.  Cycle through them nice and fast.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I ended up abandoning this project in the end